# how to get rid of Date timezone in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

The following code (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps3331333/b43k4zdc/1/))

```
var dt = new Date("2016-02-28");
console.log(dt);
```

logs

```
Sat Feb 27 2016 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Note 27 vs. 28. I need to create a var that's a date, but how to ignore the timezone?

**UPDATE:**

This solved my problem: parse manually

```
var dt = new Date("2016-02-28");
console.log(dt);
var dt2 = new Date(2016,1,28);
console.log(dt2);
```

logs

```
Sat Feb 27 2016 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Sun Feb 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Comment: use ' toLocaleDateString' method of date , example https://jsfiddle.net/b43k4zdc/2/

Comment: How did that solve your problem? That solution still will give you the timezone stuff

Comment: See update in my question

Answer (score 1):

for

```
var dt = new Date("2016-02-28");

dt.toDateString()
```

> gives you "Sun Feb 28 2016"

```
dt.toLocaleDateString()
```

> gives you "2/28/2016"

Comment: I need the date variable to be set with 2016/02/28, not to print "2016/02/28"

Comment: well all the getters in the api return in string format

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the date object in JS, then you can use `toLocaleDateString()` method, so that the date is formatted as per locale

```
var dt = new Date("2016-02-28");
console.log(dt.toLocaleDateString());
```

Output

> 2/27/2016

reference : [Javascript date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

[JavaScript toLocaleDateString() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaledatestring.asp)

Comment: I need the date variable to be set with 2016/02/28, not to print "2016/02/28"

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `getMoneth()`, `getYear()`, and `getDate()` functions to get your corresponding date. Then i just inserted it into a p tag so you can actually see it!

```js
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
var y = d.getFullYear();
var n = d.getDate();

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = m + "/" + n + "/" + y
```

```html
<p id="result">
</p>
```

Comment: I see 2/25/116 - your answer is 1 month behind and the year is not 116

Comment: It still isn't February. The month in javascript is an Array with starting index a 0. So, if you print the way you are suggesting, you need to add 1 to the month in order to get the appropriate number.

Comment: @AaronFranco thats actually the problem of Javascript so i just added 1. As you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp)

Comment: It's not a "problem of javascript," it's just the way javascript is. Now your code works properly.